# Is there any website builder like Mobirise with the forum option?

Tags: forum, bootstrap

I'm using Mobirise bootstrap builder for some time and I do really like it. It's very easy to use and the design is quite nice. But I need to create a landing page with the forum. It would be nice if this option wouldn't be very expensive. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Mobirise builder is really awesome but it really lacks the forum extension. Among the other website creators I could mention WordPress, Wix, Shopify and so on.